# Upload image on laravel

Tags: image, upload, laravel

add an image I can not load because it creates a new folder outside the public folder

```
$input = Input::all();
        $polje = array('naslov' => 'required');

        $provjera = Validator::make($input, $polje);
        if($provjera->passes()){    

            $file = Input::file('file');
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $uploadSuccess = Input::file('file')->move(base_path().'/images/vijesti', $filename);
            $vijest = new Vijesti();
            $vijest->naslov = $input['naslov'];
            $vijest->slika = $uploadSuccess;
            $vijest->tekst = $input['tekst'];
            $vijest->tag = $input['tag'];
            $vijest->kategorija_id = Input::get('kategorija_id');
            $vijest->save();
            return Redirect::to('admin/vijesti/dodaj')->withInput()->with('ok', 'Vijest je uspjesno dodata.');
        }else {
            return Redirect::to('admin/vijesti/dodaj')->with('no', 'Greska: morate pokusati ponovo, polje naslov i slika su obavezna polja.');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong function. Use `public_path()` instead of `base_path()`.

`$uploadSuccess = Input::file('file')->move(public_path().'/images/vijesti', $filename);`

Hope that helps :)